# Disable activity without fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity

That's my first question so forgive me if I do this wrong.

The question is:
I've got activity "FirstConfig.kt". When user click on specific button I'm showing fragment with biometric authenticate. Fragment is "on top", so parrent activity is "behind" him and is doing as background. How I can disable user interraction with activity but without fragment to allow click on "cancel" in biometric prompt

*function from FirstConfig.kt*

```
private fun ShowBiometricPrompt() {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down)
        .add(
            R.id.main_first_config,
            SmallBiometricAuthenticate::class.java.newInstance()
        ).commit()
}
```

I try this

`window.setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)`

But that block whole activity with fragment and user can't click on "cancel".
Can someone help me please?

@EDIT

Yes. I want too make the fragment touchable while activity is not touchable

ActivityLayout (parrent of this layout is ConstraintLayout, but stackoverflow cutting me this part of code out)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/first_config_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Przeprowadzimy teraz krótką konfigurację, aby dostować aplikację do Twoich oczekiwań"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Powiadomienia"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#111111"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_belk"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#111111"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"></View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Zmiany w grafiku" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Nowa ocena" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Zbliżająca się płatność" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Nowa wiadomość" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/graphic_nottification"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:onClick="RegisterChangeOfPushSwitch" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/mark_nottification"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:onClick="RegisterChangeOfPushSwitch" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/payment_nottification"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:onClick="RegisterChangeOfPushSwitch" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/message_nottification"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:onClick="RegisterChangeOfPushSwitch" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Zabezpieczenie"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#111111"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#111111"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"></View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:weightSum="5">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/security_biometric"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/black_border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fingerprint_black_"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/security_disable"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/black_border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_no_screen_security"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/security_pin"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/black_border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fiber_pin_black" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And he's the fragment XML (same situation as higher. Parrent of this is FrameLayout)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_small_biometric"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"

    android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fingerprint_black_"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/finger_print_icon"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="Zidentyfikuj się"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cancel_auth"
        android:text="Anuluj"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#0055A5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

That's how it look. When I set flag NOT_TOUCHABLE user can't cancel authroization ( click on "Anuluj")
[screen_with_autohrization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFhWv.png)

@EDIT2

Thanks you @РСИТ _

I made biometric prompt as activity dialog. And to get callbak from FingerPrintAPI, I created interface 'FingerPrintCallback'. Implemented him into FirstConfigActivity, and returned in BiometricDialog with parrent activity context.

Tahnk you very much guys for help :)

Comment: you want to make the fragment touchable while activity is not touchable?

Comment: Add your layout xml

Comment: @Nexicoll, I need the FrameLayout with id `main_first_config `. Where it is?

Comment: @Nexicoll look at my way with Activity like dialog. It's easy and stable,

Comment: @Nexicoll , good. It's easy way. Make my answer accepted - mark it, if not difficult. Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Activity as dialog.

Step-by-step:

1. Create Activity with bio-detect and in manifest:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".BioActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
   ```
2. In created activity xml (BioActivity.xml), add tag `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to root (LinearLayout or another):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".BioActivity"
       android:excludeFromRecents="true"
       >

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Hello World!"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
3. In java class file of your dialog activity put this code to `onCreate()` method after `setContentView();`

   ```
   public class BioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.bio_activity);

           this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
       }
   }
   ```
4. start created dialog activity, using intent and startActivity() from main activity;

Comment: Update answer: make activity like BioActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `FrameLayout` clickable using `android:clickable="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_small_biometric"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fingerprint_black_"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/finger_print_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Zidentyfikuj się"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cancel_auth"
            android:text="Anuluj"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#0055A5"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Yes. I want too make the fragment touchable while activity is not touchable`

For this purpose, you can consume the touch event in in fragment by returning `true` in `onTouch`. For example

```
SmallBiometricAuthenticate : View.OnTouchListener {
    override fun onTouch(v: View, event:  MotionEvent) {
        return true
    }
}
```

And add the `OnTouchListener` to your fragment root `view`.